# How to create Apis on Spring, that are using up to date environment values

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

I want to create API, which takes part of its input from environment (urls etc..). Basically a Jar file.

I also wan't the values being auto updated when application.properties changes. When there is change, this is called:
`org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.RefreshEndpoint#refresh`

However, I consider it bad practice to have magic env variable keys like `'server.x.url'` in the Api contract between client application and the jar. (Problem A)

That's why I'd like to use Api like this. But there's problem of old values.

```
public class MyC {
   TheAPI  theApi=null;

   void MyC(){
      theApi = new TheApi();
      theApi.setUrl( env.get("server.x.url") ); 
   }

   doStuff() {
     theApi.doStuff();  //  fails as theApi has obsolete value of server.x.url, Problem B
}
```

So either I have ugly API contract or I get obsolete values in the API calls.

I'm sure there must be Spring way of solving this, but I cant get it to my head just now.